# perl: why \(1,2) is SCALAR? How to dereference it?

Tags: perl

Here's the code:

```
$ref = \(1,2);
print "$ref\n";
print "@$ref\n";
```

It gives me:

```
SCALAR(0xa15a68)
Not an ARRAY reference at ./test.pl line 23.
```

I was trying to write a wrapper function that calls a function with unknown result type.
It should call the real function, save the result, do some other stuff and return the saved result. But it turned out that for the caller that expects a scalar value, returning an array and returning a list in parentheses are different things. This is why I tried to use references.

Comment: You want to determine the caller's context and invoke the underlying function with that same context.  See [wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unary reference operator `\` returns the references of its RHS argument. If that argument is a *list*, then a list of references is returned.

If a list is used in scalar context, the last element of that list is returned:

```
1, 2           # list of 1, 2
\(1, 2)        # list of \1, \2
$ref = \(1, 2) # list is used in scalar context
$ref = \2      # equivalent
```

Lists and Arrays are distinct: Lists are a *syntactic* construct, while an array is a *data structure*.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is this:

```
$ref = [ 1, 2 ];
```

In your code:

```
$ref = \(1,2);
```

What the right hand side does is create a list of references, instead of a reference to an array.  It's the same as this:

```
$ref = ( \1, \2 );
```

Since you're assigning that list to a scalar, all but the last item is thrown away, and  `$ref` is set to a reference to the scalar value 2, which is probably not what you want.

See [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Note that this behavior is consistent for non-literal values as well, such as subroutine calls. If you call a sub like this:

```
$val = function();
```

then the `function` sub is called in scalar context, and can choose to return a different value than if it were called in list context. (See [`perldoc -f wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html).)  If it chooses to return a list anyway, all but the last element of the list will be discarded, and that last element will be assigned to `$val`:

```
sub fun1() { return 1; }
sub fun2() { return (1,2); }
my $f1 = fun1();
my $f2 = fun2();
# $f1 is 1, and $f2 is 2

my $r1 = \( fun1() );
my $r2 = \( fun2() );
# $r1 is a ref to 1, and $r2 is a ref to 2
```

Comment: But the real function returns (1,2). I can't change it.

Comment: The real function returns the list (1,2), not some piece of literal syntax.  If you wrap a list in `[`...`]`, you get a reference to an array. So `$ref = [ real_function() ];` will work.

Comment: @MarkReed it will work if you remove that semicolon, anyway :)

Comment: The real function might return a scalar. Brackets will turn it into array ref.

Comment: Please give us more details, then, @basin.  There's a reason Perl functions are called in specific contexts (scalar or list) and can behave differently in those contexts.  You can't just stick a `\\` (or any other operator) in front of a function call and expect the same behavior (you get a reference to the result) for scalars and lists.

Comment: In the wrapper function can I detect my context and call the real function differently?